# django with docker dosen't see pillow

Tags: django, docker, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to deploy my project on django. I almost did it but django can't see installed pillow in docker container. I'm sure that it's installed pip sends me this:

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml exec web pip install pillow

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (8.1.0)
```

But when i'm trying to migrate db i see this:

```
ERRORS:
history_main.Exhibit.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
    HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install 
Pillow".
history_main.MainUser.avatar: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
```

Here are parts of Dockerfile where Pillow tries to install:

```
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev build-base 
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./req.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r req.txt
```

...

```
RUN apk update && apk add libpq
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/req.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn hello_django.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web
  volumes:
   postgres_data:
   static_volume:
   media_volume:
```

dockerfile for web:

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# lint
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install flake8
COPY . .
RUN flake8 --ignore=E501,F401 .

# install dependencies
COPY ./req.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r req.txt


#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.3-alpine

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app

# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add libpq
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/req.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy entrypoint-prod.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh $APP_HOME

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

Comment: Please add more info. Add the docker-compose and your Dockerfiles plus the req.txt

Comment: req.txt:
`asgiref==3.3.1
Django==3.1.5
Pillow==8.1.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pytz==2020.5
sqlparse==0.4.1`

Comment: And there was gunicorn in req.txt. I decided to go to previous version using git. Dockerfile and docker-compose file i added to main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem by replacing ImageField with FileField in models.py file